# Cucumber+Capybara+Rails doesn't render models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, cucumber, capybara

I have Model Product and I render it with `<%= render @products %>`. I have template _product.html.erb wich contains `<%= link_to product.name, product %>`. When I visit this page in browser on my development environment, then it shows me my products.

Now I'm running my cucumber and it doesn't see my products.

I create products in "given" with FactoryGirl like this:

```
Given(/^(\d+) products are created$/) do |n|

      n.to_i.times do
         create(:product)
      end
    end

 Then I visit my page and in "then I check it like this"


Then(/^I should see paginated products$/) do
  puts Product.all
  puts page.body
  products = Product.all
  products[0..9].each do |product|
    page.should have_selector "a", text: product.name

  end
end
```

puts Product.all prints valid products, but puts page.body prints my page without rendered products.

Here us my env.rb file:

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
World FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
```

Why does capybara not render my template?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Although `puts Product.all` prints my products, `<%= @products.count %>` in my view shows 0 for test. Weird...

Comment: which capybara driver are you using?

Comment: Default, :rack_test I believe, But selenium didn't help

Comment: In your loop you could try `page.should have_link(product.name)`

Comment: The problem is that page doesn't contain this link during running the test, but when I visit this page manually it does

Comment: i had a similar problem which cost me some time to solve, problem was that i have not been on the site i expected to be in the test, so recheck if you are really visiting the site you want to test ;)